# SOAP UI database connection wizard

Tags: .net, soapui

I am new to SOAP UI testing tool.
I am planning to create a testcase which involves connection to database.
I am having issues using the SOAP UI database connection wizard to connect to SQL server database.
I tried with all the available drivers and i am getting error "java.lang.Exception:Failed to init connection for driver"
I am able to connect to the database using .Net code and SQL management studio.
I am not sure what are the other options available to connect to Database.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and the connection works fine.
Download  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=99B21B65-E98F-4A61-B811-19912601FDC9&displaylang=en

copy the jdbc driver jar files to the **soapui\bin\ext** directory

Restart SOAP UI.

This is the directory where SOAP UI will load additional jars (that you might want to use) from. Like JDBC drivers.

Answer (score 0):

If this does not work, then copy the driver to soapui\lib and restart soapui. This works for the error: no suitable driver for jdbc:oracle:thin@......

Answer (score 0):

Do you have mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar in C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-Pro-5.0.0\lib?